# Git alias parse message

Tags: bash, sh, git-shell

I'm trying to make an alias for adding my changes, and committing them after. The commit message must be prefixed with the branch name. The message should look something like:

"[BRANCH-123] Message here"

My branches are prefixed with a subtree like 'bugfix/' or 'feature/', and I want those to be removed from the message. So far I have:

```
branch-name = "!git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"

something = "!f() { git add -A && git commit -m \"[${$(git branch-name)#*/}] $1\"; }; f"
```

However, the 'something' command says 'Bad substitution'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parameter substitution takes a variable name to operate on, not a value.

Thus, you cannot run:

```
echo "${$(somecommand)##*/}"
```

instead, you need to run:

```
var=$(somecommand)
echo "${var##*/}"
```

Thus:

```
something = "!f() { local branch; branch=$(git branch-name); git add -A && git commit -m \"[${branch#*/}] $1\"; }; f"
```

Comment: Flagged community wiki to avoid harvesting rep from an answer to a dupe.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed :)